# Adjustable width of child elements in container

Tags: css

There is parent container with child elements:

```css
.item {
  min-width: 156px;
  max-width: 188px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}

.container {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"> </div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

I need to put all items one by one. And they have to have max available width (in specified range) when container is resized. What might be solution? `flexbox` is not an option. Also items are generated by Angular and can be any number. 
I have attahced screen. There is empty place on the right side (marked with red) since I have changed windows size. But it hasn't be. There are two options. 1) New item is added if thre is enough room 2) width of all items are correlated so that there is no empty space.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqpxk.png

Comment: you can try with `display:table-cell`

Comment: what are you looking for? your question is not clear! you want to have 3 child items in a row or one below another width 100% of its parent's width? or child with same height?

Comment: can you clarify ?,and add some content so your item have some heights https://jsfiddle.net/ksnootuL/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

just change the `css` to be like that

```
.item {
  min-width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
}

.container {
  min-width:468px;
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: use percent width to avoid flex but flex must be always considered

Comment: Andrew, I can't use % since items count is not const(

Comment: if the count is not const then use javascript to dynamically count the children items and assign width or just find a way around with flex

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific when adding questions on SO. What do you want to achieve? What are your limitations and dependencies. Why is flexbox no option? *(Just remember it for the next time)*

1. Remove `display:inline` from the container!
2. Create the desired amount of columns (in this example) three.
3. Create elements (`.box`) inside them with the desired max/min-width
4. Center the `.box` elements inside the columns with `margin:0 auto`;
5. You have now a "mostly" flexible grid (without flexbox)

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid green;
  overflow: hidden; /* hacky clearfix */
}

.item {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.box {
  min-width: 156px;
  max-width: 188px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ddd;
}

.container,
.item,
.box {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="box">
      min-width: 156px; <br> max-width: 188px;
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="box">
      min-width: 156px; <br> max-width: 188px;
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="box">
      min-width: 156px; <br> max-width: 188px;
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```